# How can I send an iOS app to someone to test?

Tags: ios

I have developed an app and I would like to send it to the customer for testing on an actual device, which is the best way to do this?

Do I have to deliver the source code, build it and run it with XCode or there is an easier way?

Comment: You can use a distribution system like TestFlight, among others.

Comment: "Easier way" is a matter of opinion (and what facilities have already been set up).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Do the following steps:**

1. Take the UDID of your customer's iOS Device (Search Google for how to get the UDID of the Device)
2. Add that UDID to the Apple's Developer Portal
3. Generate the new development or AdHoc provisioning Profile with that new UDID included in it.
4. Use that new profile and generate the Application Build.
5. Then save it for adhoc purpose and you will get the IPA file. You can send that file either to client or you can upload that IPA file to [Diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) or [Apple testflight](https://testflight.apple.com/) ([Testflight App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/testflight/id899247664))

Answer (score 1):

http://mobiledan.net/2012/03/02/5-options-for-distributing-ios-apps-to-a-limited-audience-legally/

explained clearly various options for distributing your app.. either for testing or release

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to send the source code. Yuo can use ad-hoc testing: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

You need to add a customer device to your provisioning profile first.

Answer (score 1):

No. you dont need to send the source code. Use [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com/)

Here is a nice tutorial

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/testing-with-testflight/

Answer (score 1):

Add UDID of the devices to the developer portal.

Create a ad-hoc profile and a developer profile of the app from the developer portal.

Archive the app using these certificates and then upload the ipa to the testflight.

Then you can send the invitation to your testers. They need to have a testflight account or they can create using invitaion.

also have a look at this tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/48750/testflight-sdk-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Build ipa and create account upload to testflight.com and invite people to test